# HiveQL equivalent of !> in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have currently been trying to extract those values from a table that do not exist in another table. However, as the joining value contains null values - the not in, not exists and left join option do not seem to be working.

Therefore, is there a way to apply the 'not greater than' condition in the HiveQL?

For reference, this is the query that I ran, and similarly with not exists and left join ..

```
with date_prob as 
(
    select distinct visit 
    from t1
    where dt=20161124
    and dt1!=orig_ts
),

ev_data as
(
    select distinct visit 
    from t1
    where dt=20161124
    and visit is not null
    and origts is not null 
    and uid is not null
), 

fin_data as 
(
    select x.visit 
    from ev_data x
    where x.visit not in 
    (
      select distinct visit 
      from date_prob
      and visit is not null
    ) 
)
```

The query that I ran for a left join -

```
with date_prob as 
(
    select distinct id
    from t1
    where dt1='2016-11-24'
    and dt1!=orig_ts
    and (datediff(dt1,orig_ts) not in ('1','-1'))
),

ev_data as
(
    select distinct id
    from t1
    where dt1='2016-11-24'
    and id is not null
)

select x.id

from ev_data x
left join date_prob y

where y.id is null
;
```

The Data Example -

```
id        dt1           orig_ts
1     2016-11-24       2016-11-10
2     2016-11-24       2016-11-24 
3     2016-11-24       2010-01-01
4     2016-11-24       2017-01-01
5     2016-11-24       2016-11-24
6     2016-11-24       2016-11-25
7     2016-11-23       2016-11-23
```

Therefore, from this table I want to remove those Id's where there is greater than a difference of a day. Thus, the query should return values only where the ID is equal to 2,5 and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract those values from a table that do not exist in another table than you can use `left join` and filter `where second_table_key is null`.
This will work even there are NULLs in keys:

```
--this query will return records from table a that do not exist in b
select a.id
  from a left join b on a.id=b.id
 where b.id is null; --only not joined
```

Have fixed your example. it works:

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (id int,dt1 string,           orig_ts string );
insert overwrite table t1
select 1 id,    '2016-11-24' dt1,       '2016-11-10' orig_ts union all
select 2 id,    '2016-11-24' dt1,       '2016-11-24' orig_ts union all 
select 3 id,    '2016-11-24' dt1,       '2010-01-01' orig_ts union all
select 4 id,    '2016-11-24' dt1,       '2017-01-01' orig_ts union all
select 5 id,    '2016-11-24' dt1,       '2016-11-24' orig_ts union all
select 6 id,    '2016-11-24' dt1,       '2016-11-25' orig_ts union all
select 7 id,    '2016-11-23' dt1,       '2016-11-23' orig_ts;

with date_prob as 
(
    select distinct id
    from t1
    where dt1='2016-11-24'
    and dt1!=orig_ts
    and (datediff(dt1,orig_ts) not in ('1','-1'))
),

ev_data as
(
    select distinct id
    from t1
    where dt1='2016-11-24'
    and id is not null
)

select x.id
from ev_data x
left join date_prob y on x.id=y.id
where y.id is null
;

OK
2
5
6
Time taken: 14.166 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive>
```

Works as expected

Comment: I did try that but it is returning an empty result

Comment: This approach should work. Please provide exact code with data example. I will try to reproduce.

Comment: I've added both to the body of the main question. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my answer